# Flask SQLAlchemy sum function comparison

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have table that is holding some data about users. There are two fields there `like` and `smile`. I need to get data from table, grouped by `user_id` that will show if user has likes or smiles. Query that I would write in SQL looks like:

```
select sum(smile) > 0 as has_smile,
       sum(like) > 0 as has_like,
       user_id
from ratings
group by user_id.
```

This would provide output like:

```
| has_smile | has_like | user_id |
+-----------+----------+---------+
|         1 |        0 |       1 |
|         1 |        1 |       2 |
```

Is there any chance this query can be translated to SQLAlchemy (Flask-SQLAlchemy to be precise)? I know there is `db.func.sum` but I don't know how to add comparison there, and to have label. What I did for now is:

```
cls.query.with_entities("user_id").group_by(user_id).\
    add_columns(db.func.sum(cls.smile).label("has_smile"),
                db.func.sum(cls.like).label("has_like")).all()
```

but that will return exact number of smiles/likes instead of just `1/0` if there is or there is not smile/like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to operator overloading you'd do comparison the way you're used to doing in Python in general:

```
db.func.sum(cls.smile) > 0
```

which produces an SQL expression object that you can then give a label to:

```
(db.func.sum(cls.smile) > 0).label('has_smile')
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote that first, but IDE marked it as bad, so haven't tried :/ All is working fine.